# ProcessBuilder results in cannot run programm

Tags: java, process, arguments, screenshot, processbuilder

Following command works directly in console (debian):

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" cutycapt --url='https://www.google.com' --out=/home/admin/screenshot_name_new.png
```

Now i'm trying to make this work in ProcessBuilder, i tried following two things:

```
List<String> processArguments = new ArrayList<String>();
processArguments.add("/usr/bin/xvfb-run");
processArguments.add("--server-args=\"-screen 0, 1024x768x24\" /usr/bin/cutycapt");
processArguments.add("--url=https://www.google.com");
processArguments.add("--out=/home/admin/screenshot_name_new.png");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(processArguments);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Not working: /home/admin/screenshot_name_new.png (No such file or directory)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args=\"-screen 0, 1024x768x24\" /usr/bin/cutycapt --url='https://www.google.com' --out="/home/admin/screenshot_name_new.png);
```

results in:

```
 Cannot run program "\usr\bin\xvfb-run --server-args="-screen
 0,1024x768x24" \usr\bin\cutycapt --url='https://www.google.com'
 --out=/home/admin/screenshot_name_new.png": error=2, No such file or directory
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What directory are you in when you issue the console command? You might reference the final directory in a relative fashion using the `~` operator

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
processArguments.add("--server-args=\"-screen 0, 1024x768x24\" /usr/bin/cutycapt");
```

to this:

```
processArguments.add("--server-args=-screen 0, 1024x768x24");
processArguments.add("/usr/bin/cutycapt");
```

Those are two separate arguments.  And quotation marks are only used by the shell to indicate the spaces are part of the argument;  they are not needed when passing arguments to a process directly.